# CoreOS / Docker "$ fleetctl satus my.service" - ssh: handshake failed

Tags: ssh-keys, docker, coreos

Digging in to **CoreOS** clusters with **Docker** and have come upon a SSH issue while trying to learn how to work with fleet. Deploying, running services etc goes well. **SSH auth problem** occure when executing status on fleetctl.

```
$ fleetctl status hello.service
The authenticity of host 'x.x.x.x.200' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is xx:xx:xx:0d:b3:6b:d6:74:a5:59:03:4f:xx:xx:xx:xx.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes

Warning: Permanently added 'x.x.x.200' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
Error running remote command: ssh: handshake failed: ssh: unable to authenticate, 
attempted methods [publickey none], no supported methods remain
```

Understand that this is not a specific problem for fleet, but that am missing a correct ssh key change for my cluster.

Is there any smooth way to set this up or any article that describes the process to get ssh key change to work within my server cluster?

Did look for information but nothing felt really solid and i guess this is something that i want to get 100% correct in my CoreOS cluster setup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure when you log in to the initial system that you have the key added to your SSH agent and that you either provide the `-A` flag or that you specify `ForwardAgent` in your `~/.ssh/config` file.

Comment: The problem seem to be that i was using the UI for remote connections in terminal on OSX and that it did not forward the -A flag, connecting directly through terminal got it working.   

ForwardAgent is a setting on my LOCAL computer, that i specify and upon that not need to use the -A flag anymore ?

Comment: Correct. If you create a "host" entry in `~/.ssh/config` all programs should use that configuration when connecting to the host (ForwardAgent, Port, Identity, etc)